# How to order by character and number in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to order a collection by characters and numbers in Laravel, I have tried different methods but nothing seems to work the way I want it to.

The numbers I'm trying to order can always be different, the example in te code below uses the following characters and numbers:

```
M1,
M2,
M3,
M10,
M11,
R1,
R2,
R10,
R11
```

The characters + numbers are stored in the "MYSQL" database with a VARCHAR datatype.

Tried this:

```
$items = Item::where('item_id', $itemId)->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
// M1, M10, M11, M2, M3, R1, R10, R11, R2

$items = Item::where('item_id', $itemId)->orderByRaw('LENGTH(name)', 'asc')->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
// M1, M2, M3, R1, R2, M10, M11, R10, R11</i>

$items = Item::where('item_id', $itemId)->orderByRaw('CAST(name as unsigned)')->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
// M1, M10, M11, M2, M3, R1, R10, R11, R2</i>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the following order:

```
M1,
M2,
M10,
M11,
R1,
R2,
R10,
R11
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: did you tried this `$items = Item::where('item_id', $itemId)->orderByRaw('LENGTH(name)', 'asc')->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sortBy()` with flag `SORT_NATURAL`.

```php
$items = Item::where('item_id', $itemId)->get()->sortBy('name', SORT_NATURAL);
```